# PHP and Google Drive authentication frustration

Tags: php, laravel, google-drive-api

This is driving me mental. 
I have a web application and an associated Google Account. I want the web application to use this Google drive and this google drive ONLY...PERMANENTLY.

I am using google/apiclient:^2.0
I have set up a OAuth 2.0 client ID and downloaded the JSON file.

I have this:

```
 $this->client = new \Google_Client();
 $this->client->setClientId('blahblahblah.apps.googleusercontent.com');
 $this->client->setAuthConfig(base_path() . '/resources/assets/client_secret.json');
 $this->client->setApplicationName('My Web App');
 $this->client->setRedirectUri('somewhere');
 $this->client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive');
 return $this->client;
```

Now when I run...

```
$authUrl = $this->client->createAuthUrl();
echo '<a href="'.$authUrl.'">Go</a>';
```

And authenticate I get a Code...

Now my question is...what do I do with that code?

I've tried...`$this->client->authenticate('code here');`
and also `$accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode('code here);`

I keep getting either `dailyLimitExceededUnreg` or `Invalid token format`

I'm really confused and frustrated with the Google authentication API and the docs seem way out of date.

Any hints in the right direction would be amazing.

Thanks

Comment: check out this url:https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention-canonic

Answer (score 0):

To get the access token you need the following in you "somewhere" route:

```
$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
$access_token = $client->getAccessToken();
```

the access token is used to log you into your google drive

to work with google drive you need to instantiate `Google_Service_Drive`

```
$drive = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$files = $drive->files->listFiles(array())->getItems();
```

Note: access tokens are a form of user+password that expire over time so you need to fetch new ones if they expire

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this a couple of years ago and also had some difficulties with the documentation.

I went through the code to find it for you. I used this for Gmail contact list but the procedure looks the same. I'll try to explain the process I went through and I think it should help you out.

This it the part where you are. You get the code Google send you and just save it in a Session Variable

```
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $auth_code = $_GET["code"];
    $_SESSION['google_code'] = $auth_code;
}
```

Now you will have to post to oauth2 to authenticate and get your acesstoken

```
$auth_code = $_SESSION['google_code'];
$max_results = 300;
$fields=array(
  'code'=>  urlencode($auth_code),
  'client_id'=>  urlencode($google_client_id),
  'client_secret'=>  urlencode($google_client_secret),
  'redirect_uri'=>  urlencode($google_redirect_uri),
  'grant_type'=>  urlencode('authorization_code')
);

$post = '';
foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
{
  $post .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
}

$post = rtrim($post,'&');
$result = curl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',$post);
$response =  json_decode($result);

$accesstoken = $response->access_token;
```

With the token you'll be able to curl Google Drive's endpoint and get your results

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results='.$max_results.'&alt=json&v=3.0&oauth_token='.$accesstoken;
$xmlresponse =  curl($url);
```